# PS: Change Remote Desktop Services Home Folder

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am moving my users to a different fileserver and i want to start with moving the Remote Desktop Services Home Folder (so NOT the RDS User Profile).

I already copied the files and folders to the new server. Now i need to change the location in the AD User profile.

I am using powershell to do this.

So far i got the following script

```
   Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Test,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com' |     ForEach {
   $User = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)"
   $User.psbase.invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory","\\SERVERNAME\ts-$_.SamAccountName") 
   $User.setinfo()
   }
```

The script runs without errors but when i check it in AD it shows:

```
\\SERVERNAME\ts-CN=Testuser,OU=Test,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com.SamAccountName
```

This seems to be the distinguishedName (With .SamAccountName at the end) instead of the real SamAccountName

Hope someone  can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it. The scripts works like this:

First set a variable

```
$folderpath = "\\SERVERNAME"
```

Then run this script

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Test,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com' | ForEach {
   $User = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)"
   $User.psbase.invokeset   ("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory","$folderpath\ts-$($_.SamAccountName)$") 
   $User.setinfo()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a typo you did copying the code here you forgot the "." after $_

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Test,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $User = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)"
        $User.psbase.invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory","\\SERVERNAME\ts-$_.SamAccountName") 
        $User.setinfo()
    }
```

Comment: I checked and it looks like i did make a typo posting it in this forum. I did use it $_.SamAccountName. So still not working.